# Kotlin Multplatform failing to build with Failed to resolve kotlin library even though it is generated and present

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

On turning on granular metadata:

```kotlin
kotlin.mpp.enableGranularSourceSetsMetadata=true
kotlin.native.enableDependencyPropagation=false
```

The K/MP project fails to build, `kotlinx.coroutines:1.4.2-native-mt` is probably adding the atomicfu library.

```kotlin
> Task :keyboard:compileCommonMainKotlinMetadata FAILED
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: e: Failed to resolve Kotlin library: D:\Projects\KotlinProjects\keyboard-mouse-kt\keyboard\build\kotlinSourceSetMetadata\commonMain\org.jetbrains.kotlinx-atomicfu-common\org.jetbrains.kotlinx-atomicfu-common-nativeInterop.klib
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.SingleFileResolveKt$resolveSingleFileKlib$1.error(SingleFileResolve.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.SingleFileResolveKt$resolveSingleFileKlib$1.error(SingleFileResolve.kt:17)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.KotlinLibrarySearchPathResolver.resolve(SearchPathResolver.kt:149)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.KotlinLibrarySearchPathResolver.resolve(SearchPathResolver.kt:156)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.CompilerSingleFileKlibResolveStrategy.resolve(SearchPathResolver.kt:285)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.SingleFileResolveKt.resolveSingleFileKlib(SingleFileResolve.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.SingleFileResolveKt.resolveSingleFileKlib$default(SingleFileResolve.kt:23)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.metadata.KlibMetadataDependencyContainer.<init>(K2MetadataKlibSerializer.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.metadata.K2MetadataKlibSerializer.serialize(K2MetadataKlibSerializer.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.metadata.K2MetadataCompiler.doExecute(K2MetadataCompiler.kt:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.metadata.K2MetadataCompiler.doExecute(K2MetadataCompiler.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1560)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Though I see the klib are present in the respective directory the exception has mentioned:

[image: desc]

Any workaround?

Comment: Look if this could be related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41821

Comment: @shadowsheep doesn't help, `atomicfu:0.14.4` seems to fail with the same exception :( filed a new issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43911

Comment: were you able to solve it?